# Inherit dependent typedef without using struct

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14

I have some code like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef std::less<std::string> Comparator; // simplified

typedef std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, int>> Allocator; // simplified

template<class T>
struct Base
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, T, Comparator, Allocator> type; // VERY long declaration in the actual code
};

template<class T>
struct Container : public Base<T>::type
{
    Container(Allocator a) : Base<T>::type(Comparator(), a) {}
};

int main()
{
    Allocator a;
    Container<int> c(a);
}
```

Although the declarations are a bit more *fancy* in my actual code.

The *Base* struct is used so that I do not have to write the long *map* declaration multiple times.

I was wondering if there is a better way to inherit from the map without any *Base* struct?

No macros please. I hope in some way to hide the typedef in the Container class itself or something like that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on templates having an injected class name. Inside the specialization of `map<...>`, the current specialization can be referred to simply by `map`. And that injected class name is also available to derived classes (and class templates). But since it's dependent, it requires a qualified name. It looks simpler than it sounds, here's how you roll the alias into `Conatiner`:

```
template<class T>
struct Container : public std::map<std::string, T, Comparator, Allocator>
{
    using Base = typename Container::map;
    Container(Allocator a) : Base(Comparator(), a) {}
};
```

`Container::map` is the injected class name. And the alias grabs it for convenient use.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.
One more question, I am correct to assume that the same is impossible with _typedef_ instead of _using_?

Comment: @Tomas - You can use a c-style type alias `typedef typename Container::map Base;` I just prefer the `using` syntax myself, so I answered with that.

Comment: Oops, I have misspelled it when I tried it (I have different names here). Sorry for bothering you. Thanks again :D